# US-EU dual citizen working for US non-profit while living in Ireland or UK?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, payroll-taxes, citizenship

I am a full-time, salaried employee for a US non-profit based in Virginia, where I currently reside. I have citizenship of the United States and now citizenship of Italy (by descent). My fiance (soon husband) will be starting a graduate program in either Ireland or the United Kingdom this fall.

My employer has expressed interest in keeping me on working remotely, however I am trying to figure out any logistical hurdles this would entail before I go into a meeting with them discussing this possibility. I would really love to continue working for them, but can anyone explain what this would require the organization to do? I'm hearing conflicting things on this either being simple since I am a citizen, so they just fill out the I-9 and don't withhold US income taxes (I am making under the amount of the double taxation treaty), or that this will be a legal/tax nightmare for them and they'd have to hire me as an independent contractor through a UK agency.

Please help!